# Prove there's no $a\in Z_{+}$ such that $n < a < n+1$.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, induction, integers

Let $Z_+=\{1,2,\ldots\}$. The following "obvious" claim is made in Munkres' Topology textbook in Chapter 1, and I have no idea how to prove it.

> $\forall n\in Z_+$, $\not \exists a\in Z_+:$ $n<a<n+1$.

The definitions adopted are the following:

$$ Z_+=\bigcap\mathfrak a$$

where $\mathfrak a$ is the collection of all inductive subsets of $\mathbb R$ (i.e. subsets closed under addition by $1$) which contain $1$, and $\mathbb R$ is defined axiomatically as an ordered field with the LUB property. $Z$ is identified with the prime ring of $\mathbb R$ and we identify $Z_+$ with $\{x \in Z: 0<x\}$. Rationals are the field of fractions of $Z$, etc.

Other than that I'm not assuming anything.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that $Z_+\setminus\{\,x\in \Bbb R\mid x<1\,\}$ is inductive, hence $x<1$ implies $x\notin Z_+$.

Next let $A=\{\,n\in Z_+\mid \neg \exists x\in Z_+\colon n-1<x<n\,\}$. As just seen, $1\in A$.
Also, if $n\in A$, then you can show that  $Z_+\setminus\{\,x\in \Bbb R\mid n<x<n+1\,\}$ is inductive, hence there is no $x\in Z_+$ with $n<x<n+1$, in other words: $n\in A$ implies $n+1\in A$.
We conclude that $A$ is inductive, hence $Z_+\subseteq A$. From this, the claim follows.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it directly with peano arithmetic, first you would prove $Z_+ \in \mathfrak a$ which is either trivial if done using intuition or very hard if doing it formally.

Then you would prove the theorem of induction, here is an answer that you can adapt to that end:  [How to prove structural induction theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2318902/97045) I suggest adapting Max's answer.

Then you would actually prove the theorem itself using the tools of peano arithmetic, here are some answers that do that: [Use an induction argument to prove that for any natural number $n$, the interval $(n,n+1)$ does not contain any natural number.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1612514/97045) I suggest my response if you want formality or mjqxxx's answer if you want a more intuitive response.

Comment: Great information. Thank you